# Email clients changing my links & to &amp;

Tags: google-maps, email

I am sending out email alerts with a static google map on them.  Certain email clients are changing the content of the link so that it no longer works.  Specifically,  "&" is getting changed to & a m p ; (no spaces)

Google will not accept the link with the substitutions.  I have also tried sending %26 in place of &, but google will not accept that.  This is only happening on certain systems like AOL and maybe Hotmail.

Here's an example link:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=36.124023600000,-115.170356400000&size=500x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=label:S%7Ccolor:red%7C36.114646000000,-115.172816000000&markers=label:H%7Ccolor:green%7C36.124023600000,-115.170356400000

Is there anyway to tell the email client NOT to change the link, or is there anyway to change the original link to work with Google and bypass the email client substitution?

TIA,

David

Comment: Which email client are you using to send the messages out?

Answer (score 1):

Your email program is probably telling the receiving programs what type of message it is.  There is a header "Content-Type:" which is usually either "text/plain" or "text/html", with it defaulting to text/plain.

Probably what is happening is that your message is going out as text/html, and the receiving program is rendering as HTML, but first fixing things up so that ampersands get displayed as ampersands instead of as HTML directives.  Otherwise, if I send a message that says "John & Carol are having a surprise party", the ampersand will screw things up or not get shown.  (I forget right now which.)

It is also possible that your email program is doing the conversion before the message gets sent out and most of the receiving email programs are recognizing the issue and fixing it.

In order to tell exactly what is going on, send yourself one of these alerts and view the source.  How you view the source varies depending upon which email program you use to read the message.  With GMail, open the message, and in the upper right hand of the message, there is a drop-down "More"; choose "show original".  Look for what the content type is and whether the ampersands in the URL are & or `&amp;`.

Now, as to how to fix it, probably what you are doing right now is just typing the URL into the message.  Instead, try making it a link.  How you do this will vary depending upon which program you use to compose, but on GMail for example, there is a little symbol like a chain.  Press that button and enter in the URL.  That will generate HTML something like
`<a href="http://mydomain.com/blah/blah?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3>http://mydomain.com/blah/blah?foo=1&amp;bar=2&amp;baz=3</a>`
Thus, even if the ampersands get *displayed* as `&amp;`, when the user *clicks* on the link, they will get the URL with proper ampersands.

I can't be certain this will work, as I don't know what email program you are using and thus how it does things.  However, I think it is *likely* to work.

If it doesn't, you might be able to get it to work by sending as text/plain instead of text/html.